# in selenium find the following sibling of an element with a specific child css selector

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I have a tree like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td>
  <span>MySpan1</span>
 </td>
<tr>
<tr>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <div>
   <a title="my_title1"></a>
  </div>
 <td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>
  <span>MySpan2</span>
 </td>
<tr>
<tr>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <div>
   <a title="my_title2"></a>
  </div>
 <td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need to select `<a title="my_title2"></a>` knowing that its `tr` parent must have a sibling `tr/td/span[contains(text(),'MySpan2')]`

If it is not possible with css selector, then can it be achieved with xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this xpath

```
//span[contains(text(),'MySpan2')]/ancestor::tr/following-sibling::tr[2]/descendant::a[@title='my_title2']
```

we are targeting `MySpan2` span then go to `ancestor` which is `tr`  then we have to go to it's second `following-sibling` and then target a tag with title `my_title2`

You cannot use `css selector` for this, `xpath` is only choice.

We are traversing upward in `HTMLDOM` so `css` has to be ruled out.

Please refer [xpath axes](http://terraform%20init%20-backend-config=%22bucket=terraform-384126748274%22%20-backend-config=%22region=us-east-1%22)

**Update :**

Irrespective of `tr` sibling number :

```
//span[contains(text(),'MySpan2')]/ancestor::tr/following-sibling::tr/descendant::a[@title='my_title2']
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks!
I had to change just following-sibling::tr[1] and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: The convention in SO is to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick/check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Actually, I found out it's not the best solution as It is not certain how many <tr> under MySpan2 I have. E.g.:```<tr>
 <td>
  <span>MySpan2</span>
 </td>
<tr>
<tr>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <div>
   <a title="my_title2"></a>
  </div>
 <td>
</tr><tr>
<tr>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <div>
   <a title="my_title3"></a>
  </div>
 <td>
</tr>```   But it is certain about the title name. Is it possible to find the sibling of a known title name?

Comment: Check the update above.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:
`//span[contains(text(),'MySpan2')]/ancestor::tr/following-sibling::tr/td/div/a[@title='my_title2']`